# Eigenvalues and Eigenspace Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Thank you ahead of time for the help, I am having a problem with part $4$. I understand parts $1$ and $2$ and $3$ and have solved them but I cant seem to understand $4$. If someone could help me out, that would be amazing.

> Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -4 & -6\\-1 & 0 & -3\\1 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$
>
> 1. Find the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of $A$.
> 2. Find a basis for each eigenspace.
> 3. Is $A$ diagonalizable? If yes, diagonalize $A$.
> 4. Find $A^{10}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
If you know the characteristic polynomial, then express $x^{10}=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $q(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial and $r(x)=0$ or,degree of $r(x)$ is less than or equal 2. Then by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^{10}=r(A)$.

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: @ user161059. Okay, Please can you type the characteristic polynomial. I am sorry I didn't compute it

Comment: Also we can play with the minimal polynomial $(x-5)(X-4)$ if computation is relatively fast-track.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to do the following:

$A^{10}=(S^{-1}DS)^{10}=S^{-1}DS \cdot S^{-1}DS\cdot....\cdot S^{-1}DS=S^{-1}D^{10}S$ (Because $S^{-1}S=I$)

For your diagonalizable matrix A and the diagonal matrix D

*Edit:*

For more information see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_diagonalization#Diagonalization

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B0%2C-4%2C-6%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%2C-3%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C5%7D%7D

Note: In the second link you can see that your eigenvalues are actually **wrong**. The eigenvalues of the matrix are $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_{2,3}=2$

If you don't know how to compute them, ask a new question.

Comment: for one of the questions i got 
D= 4 0 0,
   0 5 0,
   0 0 5, 
  how would i do this to a 10th power...how would i approach it...

Comment: Just multiply two diagonal matrices and you will see that the rule for diagonal matrices is: If $D=( \lambda_1, \lambda_2,..., \lambda_m)$ is a diagonal matrix, then $D^n=( \lambda_1^n, \lambda_2^n,..., \lambda_m^n)$

Comment: what you are saying is 4^10, 5^10, 5^10? add them up? and thats A^10th?

Comment: $D^{10}$=\begin{pmatrix} 4^{10} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5^{10} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5^{10}  \end{pmatrix}

Comment: yea thats what i got and then do i add them up or something or what do i do with them after that?

Comment: Compute $S^{-1}D^{10}S$ and you are done.

Comment: see thats where u are losing me...i dont know what S is...i got DPP^-1....i dont see S anywhere in the chapter...

Comment: S is the transformation matrix, such that $S^{-1}AS=D$. D is your diagonal matrix which you computed before (it contains your eigenvalues, they have to be linear independent!) and S is the matrix which contains three different eigenvectors in its column. Well, above i wrought $SAS^{-1}=D$ in that case the matrix which contains the eigenvectors is $S^{-1}$. It is important that in the formula $S^{-1}AS=D$ the matrix on the right side is the matrix which contains the eigenvectors and the matrix on the left side is its inverse. I edited a link above.